# Document library migration from Moss07 to SP2010

Tags: 2007, migration, content-migration, document-migration

I am trying to migrate a SharePoint "Shared Document" document library from MOSS07 site to SP2010 site. I am using the tool called metalogix but when I select the list, it hangs, and stops responding due to large contents.

The document library is having almost 25000 items. Is there any other way, may be OOTB? Is Saving lists as template can be considered as an option? or any alternatives?

What should be best to migrate this document library successfully to SP2010 site?

Comment: You can give it a try for saving a list as template including content.

Comment: 25k items will not allow for that.

Comment: I have tried saving it as a template, it throws error as "The list is too large to save as a template. The size of a template cannot exceed 10485760 bytes."  Even if I increase the size to max 50 MB, not sure, if it will resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a path in the "C:\ProgramData\Metalogix" in which the XML file is "EnvironmentSettings" responsible for all thresholds and overall performance. so you need to update that to make it work.

Pls see the detailed note from the metalogix documentation: 
**For large lists, we recommend starting with batch sizes of between 100 to 200 items. For smaller or larger lists with larger items, we recommend setting the parameter “UploadManagerDetermineBatchSizesByMB” to True, and then setting the parameter “UploadManagerBatchSizeThresholdInMB” to between 300MB and 500MB.**

Also based on my experience, it is always better to configure the settings in the  tool and then generate the powershell script to run so it will improve the overall performance.

**Additionally, DB connection is the best approach to start with when you have large content to migrate.**